# Different methods approach with WCF Service for IOS App: one sends json and another uses querystring data

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, wcf, web-config

I've developed a wwebservice in c# that permit to an ios app to send data on the server. My service works perfectly when I "upload" data with a JSON structure. Now I need to add a method that accept data as query string. I will explain better:
I need a method that can works inside my IOS App and also across a web browser.
The method is declared in this way:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "testquerystring?id={value}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        string test(string value);
```

and the simply implementation is:

```
   public string test (string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

The result in the debug area of xcode is a beautiful: null.

Instead the method that works (in the same service) is this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "postM2Data", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
string saveImg(List<me2Data> data);
```

with this DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class me2Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool _isPrivate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string _userCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string _img { get; set; }
}
```

To complete the request this is the relative configuration of the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Me2WebServices.service">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="Me2WebServices.Iservice"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
```

Somebody can suggests me some solution? 
Thanks in advice

**RESOLVED WAS MY MISTAKE**
I cannot return a simple string object! I have to create a json and return the object!
So my class is became:

```
public retData test (string value)
{
   retData = retValue = new retData();
   retValue.value = value;
   return value;
}
```

Whit this DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class retData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string value { get; set; }

}
```

Now works!

Comment: How are you sending the data to the service (in both GET and POST cases)? Also, not really related to your problem, but it's preferred to use `[WebGet]` instead of `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]`

Comment: Hallo... I'm using [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")] because I can define an urltemplate right?!?